# How do I create a command to add rows to a tabularray?

Tags: tabularray

So I have a command to add entries to a table (because I'm adding an unknown number).

I can't figure out why it works when I enter it by hand but not when I use the `\addentry` command—can anyone help?

```
\newcommand{\addentry}[5]{
    {#1} & {#2} & \faMapMarker\hspace{.5ex}{#3} & \faCalendar\hspace{.5ex}{#4} \\
    #5 &&& \\
    }

\begin{tblr}{
        colspec = {@{}Q[l]Q[l]Q[r]Q[r]@{}},
        hlines,
        vlines,
        width = \linewidth,
        cell{even}{1} = {c=4}{\linewidth,halign=j},
        row{odd} = {
            valign = m,
            halign = r,
            font   = \sc
        },
        row{even} = {
            halign = j
        },
    }
        First Entry & Second Entry & Third Entry & Fourth Entry \\
        \lipsum\\
        \addentry{First entry}
        {Second entry}
        {Third entry}
        {Fourth entry}
        {Fifth, multi-line entry }
    \end{tblr}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\begin{tblr}[expand=\addentry]{
...
```